# Saving req to global variable in nodejs server

Tags: node.js

What are the consequences of making request global (or singleton), so that it is accessible all over the server and does not have to be passed in each function call? For example:

index.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const { saveReq } = require('./shared');

const {
    doSomethingWithReqPassingItAsParameter,
    doSomethingWithReqPassingItAsGlobal
} = require('./lib');

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    // approach 1
    doSomethingWithReqPassingItAsParameter(req);

    // approach 2
    saveReq(req);
    doSomethingWithReqPassingItAsGlobal();

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('Hello, World!');
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(8080);
```

lib.js:

```
const { loadReq } = require('./shared');

const doSomethingWithReqPassingItAsParameter = (req) => {
    console.log('req as parameter', req.url);
};

const doSomethingWithReqPassingItAsGlobal = () => {
    console.log('req as global', loadReq().url);
};

module.exports = {
    doSomethingWithReqPassingItAsParameter,
    doSomethingWithReqPassingItAsGlobal,
};
```

shared.js

```
var request;

const saveReq = (r) => request = r;
const loadReq = () => request;

module.exports = {
    saveReq,
    loadReq,
}
```

This is very convenient for large projects with many levels of function calls, but how parallel requests will be handled? I know that nodejs is single-threaded, does it mean than each http request will be run from end to finish separately or they can overlap, thus using a global request object would make a mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consequences are that your server will only work for one request at a time and as soon as you have more than one request in flight at the same time, data will be mixed up between requests dealing to bugs, crashes, security issues and incorrect results.

Simply put, you cannot program a server that way. Pass the `req` object or data from it to any functions that need it. That keeps the appropriate `req` object associated with the right execution to avoid all the problems of trying to store a `req` object in some sort of global location where multiple requests in flight at the same time will/can conflict.

There is a relatively new thing in nodejs called "async local storage" that could perhaps be used for this.  You can read a little about it [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/async-local-storage-nodejs/), though it's my personal opinion that it's still better to pass your request data to the functions that want to use it rather than the async local storage for this.